# Pycharm: file not runnable msg

Tags: pycharm

I just installed the latest version of Pycharm. I’m new to python and Pycharm and python so I didn’t deviate from the ‘vanilla’ installation for either. I installed python from python.org and Pycharm (I’ve tried both community and pro) from Jetbrains. Python was installed first. When I create a project and write a simple line of code I cannot run it. The run button says file not runnable. I checked to see if the python.axe was shown in the interpreter settings and it shows as python 3.12 for my project. It seems like Pycharm should know where python.axe is but when I check the python.exe by the show all in the interpreter path the python.exe file that is listed in the dropdown has a question mark next to it as if it does not recognize that it’s an .exe file. Any help would be appreciated

I’ve uninstalled and reinstalled both python and Pycharm taking care of where I was getting the installation files from.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, stupid me. Pycharm showed ‘current file’ at the top for the configuration file. I changed that to the project file and I can now run the program. Not sure of the logic when it shows current file and that, apparently, it’s not? the current file it’s set to?? But, I just learned something just by poking around :-)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).